# Codeigniter 3.x / form_input() / preappend or append / bootstrap 3.x

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

How is is possible to include a prepend icon or an append icon using form_input();

```
<?php                             
$email = array(
         'name'        => '',
         'value'       => '',
         'id'          => null,   
         'placeholder' => 'Email',
         'class'       => 'mail form-control'
         );

echo form_input($email);
?>
```

What I would like to do is add, for example, the following bootstrap 3 styling to the email input box:

```
<span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon2">@example.com</span>
```

I am unsure how that would fit into the array.  I have looked at the manual for CI3, however, it does not mention anything in particular.  Any suggestions, etc, appreciated.

This is what I am aiming for:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you can't. `form_input()` is used to build the input element **only**. If you take a closer look at the html structure. `<span>` comes right after `<input>` and not within `<input>`. So, you have to add it after the input element

```
....
<?php echo form_input($email); ?>
<span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon2">@example.com</span>
...
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Taking code from bootstrap website:

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="form-group has-success has-feedback">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="inputSuccess3">Input with success</label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputSuccess3" aria-describedby="inputSuccess3Status">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span id="inputSuccess3Status" class="sr-only">(success)</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group has-success has-feedback">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="inputGroupSuccess2">Input group with success</label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
      <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon">@</span>
        <?php                             
        $email = array(
            'type'        => 'text',
            'class'       => 'form-control'
            'id'          => 'inputGroupSuccess2',
            'aria-describedby' => 'inputGroupSuccess2Status',
            'name'        => 'email',//name field is mandatory to be able to control it in form_validation library
            'placeholder' => 'Email',
        );

        echo form_input($email);
        ?>
      </div>
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span id="inputGroupSuccess2Status" class="sr-only">(success)</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

you can see that span tag and input tag doesn't collide. So you would just use:

```
<?php                             
$email = array(
    'name'        => '',
    'value'       => '',
    'id'          => null,   
    'placeholder' => 'Email',
    'class'       => 'mail form-control'
);

echo form_input($email);
?>
```

instead of bootstrap input field. Everything else can stay the same in view file. If you would like to make input field like second one from example above, you should code it like:

```
<?php                             
$email = array(
    'type'        => 'text',
    'class'       => 'form-control'
    'id'          => 'inputGroupSuccess2',
    'aria-describedby' => 'inputGroupSuccess2Status',
    'name'        => 'email',//name field is mandatory to be able to control it in form_validation library
    'placeholder' => 'Email',
);

echo form_input($email);
?>
```

This could be example like "Optional icons in horizontal and inline forms" on [Forms page](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms).

Comment: Thank you buy sorry, could not get it working; just a text box and the allocation for an icon is there in the beginning but nothing appearing.

But actually, am trying to figure out how to get this incorporated:  <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon2">@example.com</span>

Comment: Edit your question with all form posted to let me see.

Comment: Thank you again but I am aware of mail form-control and how to get a prepended email icon, however, I am unable to figure out how to get an appended input box with '@example.com' at the end.  Any solution for that?

Comment: You have to post code from view file to let me help you. Post all form from view file to let me see what have you got there so far.

Comment: I don't have anything to post as I do not know how to append "@example.com" to an input box.  I have only this:

$email = array(
    'name'        => '',
    'value'       => '',
    'id'          => null,   
    'placeholder' => 'Email',
    'class'       => ''
);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102756/discussion-between-tpojka-and-user3264461).

Comment: You need first make view file with form. You can use some template from bootstrap site as I did in answer.

Comment: I have everything set up already.  I am just missing how to append @example.com using form_input() ... any idea how?

Comment: Third time: post what have you set up. I can't offer any solution if I don't see how exactly you form looks like.

Comment: here is my view file:

<div class="container">
                          <?php
                          $email = array(
                          'type'        => 'text',
                          'class'       => '',
                          'id'          => 'email',
                         
                          'name'        => 'email',
                          'placeholder' => 'Email',
                          );
                               echo form_input($email);
                          ?>
               
</div>

Comment: Please edit your question and include that code to be readable.

Comment: It is the same as the original post.

Comment: You didn't make valid form in your view file. Use some samples [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp) or [here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms). Make one of these in your view file. If you get some errors, post code from view file that includes whole form and that way you'll help us to help you. Otherwise I can't help more, sorry.

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding my question.  I am trying to figure out how to add append text to the input box using form_input().  I can build up the form later but is there any way to do it within form_input();  It is not a form submission issue or anything like that... simply trying to add "@example.com" on the right had side of the input box (see the graphic in the original question).  Thanks.

Comment: Check what is looks like on sample I provided you. Since I don't have your exact form, you should take conclusion what to do next. So answer would be you can place PHP variable in the middle of HTML code there. If you put `form_input($email)` before appended span element, it will be shown as on your image.